# how to setup class based on deserialized json?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this returned json that I am trying to create a class for in c#.  I cannot seem to get the correct mapping based on the json that I am trying to consume.

I tried to copy the json and then in visual studio do a Paste Special -> Paste Json as classes option but that did not do the trick.  The data returned in say class.value was blank.

```
{
    "status": {
        "type": "success",
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Success",
        "error": false
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "status": "Authenticated",
            "expires_at": "2019/10/09 11:48:08 +0000",
            "user": {
                "username": "xxxx",
                "email": "xxxx@yahoo.com",
                "firstname": "Steve",
                "id": 11111,
                "lastname": "xxxx"
            },
            "session_token": "XXXX",
            "return_to_url": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Any starting point would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: You can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) for creating c# classes from json

Comment: @evgiv0 I honestly wouldn't recommend it. Especially if the JSON contains types like Dictionaries, etc.

Comment: What classes did you make

Comment: *Paste Json As Classes* worked fine for me with your JSON.  Can you edit your question to include the classes that you generated, as well as show how you are attempting to deserialize your JSON into them?  It would be a lot easier to help if we could see what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for all the input but I got it working.  I had it all rolled up under class and when I was trying to deserialize the json object I was still referring to an older class that I was no longer using.  It did work using json2csharp and also using visual stuido

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JsonClass 
{
    public JsonClass(){}
    public ResponseStatus status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ResponseData> data {get; set;}
}

public class ResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus(){}

    public string type {get; set;}
    public int code {get; set;}
    public string message {get; set;}
    public bool error {get; set;}
}

public class ResponseData 
{
    public string status {get; set;}
    public DateTime expires_at {get; set;}
    public ResponseUser user {get; set;}
    public string session_token {get; set;}
    public string return_to_url {get; set;}
}

public class ResponseUser 
{
    public string username {get; set;}
    public string email {get; set;}
    public string firstname {get; set;}
    public string lastname {get; set;}
    public int id {get; set;}
}
```

### Using something like Json.NET:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(json);
```

I utilize Json.NET a ton in my work and personal projects. You can find more information on it here. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

So really all you're doing is defining classes with properties that will map to the the supplied JSON Array / Object structure. Then utilizing a library like Json.NET you can map them back and forth utilizing `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object);` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);`